# Counting the number of occurrences

Tags: r

I have the following problem. I want to count the number of occurrences of values that are smaller or equal to zero. Example in the following data I have 3 occurrences 1(0,0,0),2(-1,-2),3(0,0). Is there any build in function in R to count the successive occurrences.

```
a <- c(2,4,5,3,2,4,7,0,0,0,4,3,2,-1,-2,3,2,0,0,4)
```

Comment: @Jaap OP seems to want to count the number of runs of items <= 0, not the number of elements.

Comment: In that case I have 7 occurrences. I don`t want to sum the values that are smaller or equal to zero, but the occurrences in the series in my case 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `rle`:

```
> sum(rle(a<=0)$values)
[1] 3
```

Explanation:

`rle` breaks the vector into runs which are > 0 or <= 0. The `$values` are either `true` or `false` depending on whether or not the corresponding run satisfies the predicate (`a <= 0`) or its negation. You want the runs corresponding to the value `TRUE`, the function `sum` coerces those `TRUE`s to 1.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to count the number of runs with values below zero:

```
sum(rle(a <= 0)$values)
```

which gives:

```
[1] 3
```

How this works:

- With the `rle` function you create a runlength-encoding of `a <= 0`.
- The output of `rle(a <= 0)` is:

  ```
  Run Length Encoding
    lengths: int [1:7] 7 3 3 2 2 2 1
    values : logi [1:7] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE ...
  ```
- Now you just have to sum the values part of the `rle`-object:

  ```
  > sum(rle(a <= 0)$values)
  [1] 3
  ```

Comment: Is it possible to use rle for logical values? To count the occurrences of TRUE and FALSE?

Comment: @kelamahim do you mean something like `rl <- rle(a <= 0); sum(rl$lengths[rl$values])` ?

Comment: My output looks like: TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE, so to count the occurrence of TRUE, in this case i have 2

Comment: I think the rle is just for atomic vectors

Comment: @kelamahim that is what the solution in my answer is doing ...  isn't it?

Comment: Ups, apologies ! Thank you one more time

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer using `rle` is a good one, but here's another way to do it:

```
b <- a <= 0
sum(b) - sum(b[which(b) - 1])
```

This counts the number of non-positive elements, and subtracts the count of how many of these were preceded by a non-positive element (so only the start of each run of non-positives ends up contributing.)

I did a quick test and found this runs a few times quicker for large vectors (10 million to 300 million elements).

```
v1 <- function(a) sum(rle(a<=0)$values)

v2 <- function(a) {
  b <- a <= 0
  sum(b) - sum(b[which(b) - 1])
}

v1.time <- NULL
v2.time <- NULL
sizes <- 1:30 * 1E7
for (s in sizes) {
  x <- sample(-100:100, s, replace = TRUE)

  v1.time <- c(v1.time, system.time(
    v1.result <- v1(x)
  )[['elapsed']])

  v2.time <- c(v2.time, system.time(
    v2.result <- v2(x)
  )[['elapsed']])

  print(c(v1.result, v2.result)) # Show that they agree
  print(v1.time)
  print(v2.time)
}

library(tidyverse)
data.frame(VectorSize = sizes,
           v1 = v1.time,
           v2 = v2.time) %>%
  gather('Version', 'Time', -VectorSize) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = VectorSize, y = Time, color = Version)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()
```

[image]

Comment: nice alternative!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option (not repeating the same stuff) using `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
uniqueN(rleid(a<=0)[a<=0])
#[1] 3
```

The `rleid` gives the run-length-id of the logical vector (`a <=0`), subset the ids with the logical vector (`[a<=0]`) and find the `length` of the `unique` ids with `uniqueN`

---

Or a `base R` approach would be

```
sum(diff(a <=0)==1)
#[1] 3
```

Comment: how could I forget about `rleid` ;-)

Comment: btw: `sum(diff(a <=0)==1)` won't give the correct output when the vector starts with a `0`

Answer (score 0):

In this example how do I count all the occurrences in all replications?

```
set.seed(3)
b<-c(4,6,4,2,3)
run<- replicate(2,{
a <- runif(5,3,5)
dif <- a - b
return(dif)
})
run
 [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.6639169  0.2087881
[2,] -1.3849672 -2.7507331
[3,] -0.2301153 -0.4107982
[4,]  1.6554686  2.1552198
[5,]  1.2042013  1.2619585
```

When I try

```
sum(rle(run<=0)$values)
```

I get

```
Error in rle(run <= 0) : 'x' must be a vector of an atomic type
```

but it is working with

```
uniqueN(rleid(run<=0)[run<=0])
```